# D3 can't render GeoJson file (Simple structure in Montreal, Canada) created in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, d3, canada

I am attempting to render SVG and attach it to a div with id="map". I can do this successfully with GeoJson which I acquired from this tutorial: http://maptimeboston.github.io/d3-maptime/#/1

Excerpt:

```
var neighborhoods_json = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "Roslindale", "density": 5.5800 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -71.1259, 42.2720 ], [ -71.1257, 42.2723 ], [ -71.1256, 42.2724 ] etc...
```

I am rendering this using the following code:

```
var width = 960, height = 720;
var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

var albersProjection = d3.geo.albers()
  .scale(190000).rotate([71.057,0]).center([0, 42.313])
  .translate([width/2, height/2]);

var geoPath = d3.geo.path().projection(albersProjection);

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(neighborhoods_json.features)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
  return colors(i);})
  .attr('d', geoPath);
```

This works great, as Boston is in the USA and Albers is an appropriate choice of projection.

The data which I need to render, however, is a simple movie theater traced over a location in Montreal, Canada using QGIS ( [http://imgur.com/Dddkci2](https://imgur.com/Dddkci2) ). I saved the layer as GeoJson using a setting of EPSG:4326, WGS 84. This results in the following file being added to my project:

```
var theater_json = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":     "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "d3Css": "l0r0" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -73.433681281940878, 45.445198056579976 ], [ -73.433681281940878, 45.445201593863992 ], [ -73.433916566065932, 45.445339547768 ], etc...
```

I am unable to render this in my project. The svg is appended, but regardless of whether I choose to append it as 'path' or 'polygon', the segments are all 0x0 and no visualization is created. I am confused whether or not a projection should be used, as I have seen suggestions of utilizing a projection of "null" in case the data was already outputted with a projection from QGIS. I have also seen suggestions that Canadian locations should use the mercator projection. In any case, here is how the code currently stands:

```
var svg2 = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

var mercProjection = d3.geo.mercator();
var theaterPath = d3.geo.path().projection(mercProjection);

svg2.selectAll('path')
  .data(theater_json.features)
  .enter()
  .append('Polygon')
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors(i);})
  .attr('d', theaterPath);
```

Regardless of whether I use mercator, null, or any other variety of projection (stereographic, azimuthal equidistant, azimuthal equal area), I am never able to render any visualization. The paths/polygons, however, are still being created with segments of 0x0 in every case. Such an observation seems to suggest that the wrong projection is being chosen, as I observe the same behaviour when I choose the wrong projection for the Boston data.

Comment: P.S. My Montreal theater data works just fine on http://geojson.io  (Screenshot: http://imgur.com/A4wlTgM )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the projection's scale since you're trying to show a small area.

Here's a polygon around Montreal:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/302378c7c02cff2450231a77068c5870

Here's code to draw it with d3:  https://bl.ocks.org/swingley/9441b02dd565b6caa3b9f388cbd077bb

The relevant JS for defining the projection:

```
var mercator = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([ -73.6, 45.5 ])
  .translate([ w * 0.5, h * 0.6 ])
  .scale([ w * 128 ]);
```

Comment: You, sir, have gifted me with a golden egg. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is curious about what projection I ended up using for the data I was working with, it's this:

```
var mercator = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([ -73.438, 45.447 ])
  .translate([ width * 0.1, height * 0.2 ])
  .scale([ 8000000 ]);
```